# Deleting an element from a specific position in a dynamic array in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around pointers and memory management in C.

In this particular instance, I'm trying to delete an element from within a dynamically allocated array.

Consider the following lines of code:

```
void deleteElemFromPosition(VectorDinamic *v, unsigned int poz){
int nCap = v->capacity;
Element* nElems = malloc(nCap * sizeof(Element));

int i;
for (i = 0; i < v->lg; i++) {
    if(i!=poz)nElems[i] = v->elems[i];
    else{
            nElems[i]=v->elems[i+1];
            ++i;

    }
}

free(v->elems);
v->elems = nElems;
v->capacity = nCap;
}
```

This piece creates a copy of the array that I'm trying to copy with one difference. It doesn't store the element at the wanted position, but rather than doing so, it seems to enter an infinite loop, or actually, not infinite but very very big. So big that it makes the program crash.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Maybe I should have included the definition of the dynamic array from the beginning. Oh well.

```
VectorDinamic * creazaVectorDinamic() {
VectorDinamic *v = malloc(sizeof(VectorDinamic));
v->elems = malloc(INIT_CAPACITY * sizeof(Element));
v->capacitate = INIT_CAPACITY;
v->lg = 0;
return v;
```

Comment: What part has the bug? Have you tried commenting out portions of the code until it doesn't crash?

Comment: What are `v->lg` and `v->capacity` set to in this case? How big is `v->elems`? (at least "`lg`" long I assume)

Comment: @mike
`v->lg` is the current length of the array.
`nCap` is, I believe, redundant. It's left over from another piece of code. That piece is used to extend the maximum capacity of the dynamic array. `nCap` is the new capacity

Comment: @staticx
If I understood your question correctly then the loop is bugged. The program actually enters the loop, but it doesn`t exit it and crashes.

Comment: @JohnB: What I am getting at is if you point to the exact line in your code and tell us, this one causes it to crash when you run it then we will be more apt to help you. It is hard to get good answers with what you provided because we would have to step through your code, which you should have already done. I am not trying to be mean or rude and please don't take it that way. Just trying to help you so I can help you :)

Comment: @staticx No offense taken, but my poor understanding of general C philosophy is a hindrance. I don't have a good grasp on pointers in C. It's also hard because I don't know what kind of information would be useful to you, so you can help me.

But in this particular instance, the problem lies with the 
`for (i = 0; i < v->lg; i++)` construction, as `v->lg` yields a really high number. But what really bugs me is the fact that the same piece of code is used, and works, to extend the maximum capacity of the dynamic array.

Comment: If you do a `printf("%d", v->lg);` assuming it is an integer and you get a large number, then you are looking at garbage values. Your edited in code shows you are setting it to 0, so the loop technically shouldn't run at all.

Comment: I only attached the definition of the array. In between that and what I posted before that there's other actions being taken, one of which being the storage of 3 elements into the array.

Comment: How is `lg` being incremented?

Comment: Like so:

`void add(VectorDinamic *v, Element el) {
    printf("%d ",v->lg);
 if (v->lg == v->capacitate) {
  resize(v);
 }
 //printf("%d",v->lg);
 v->elems[v->lg] = el;
 v->lg++;
}
`

Comment: It's possible that while you are doing that operation, the memory for that object is going out of scope and so you lose any changes once `add` ends.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems. For a start:

1. You do not need to `malloc()` a completely new array then copy things in. Just shuffle down the ones above the element you are deleting using `memmove`, then `realloc` to shrink the allocated memory.
2. Your loop increments `i` twice, once in the `for` loop, and once in the `else` clause.
3. There seems to be some confusion between `v->capacity` and `v->lg`. What is the difference between these two?

In general, telling us *where* and *how* it crashes would be useful, as would the definition of `VectorDinamic` (note *dynamic* is spelt thus). Try using `gdb` or similar.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid the language barrier might cause some issues.

Thanks for the `memmove` suggestion, I`ll try that and report back.

As for your second point, yes. I am aware that `i` gets incremented twice, because when `i` reaches the value of `poz` we don't need to store that value and we skip it.

Comment: So this is what I did:

`void deleteElemFromPosition(VectorDinamic *v, unsigned int poz){
    unsigned int i;

    for(i=poz;i<v->lg;i++){
        memmove(v->elems[i],v->elems[i+1],sizeof(Element));
    }


    }
`

But the program still crashes. 

I suspect the problem lies with the end condition in the `for` loop.

EDIT:Yep, printing it(`v->lg`) yields 7083328.

Comment: @JohnB: That's a garbage value, you are reading memory that either doesn't belong your object or from the wrong position. Need to look at your design a little more closely.

Answer (score 1):

In this way is very difficult to find the bug. There could be multiple elements that makes your program crash, like the `malloc(nCap * sizeof(Element))` that can return `null` on error, or `free(v->elems);` if `v->elems` is statically allocated or if `null`. We don't know what is `v->lg`...
Try to debug with `gdb` or `valgrind`.